# How to use response header location with static HTTPClient in C#

Tags: c#, response-headers

The below code is working fine for me and I use this httpclient to send requests to endpoints. In the response header I am getting location uri for the subsequent call.I want to use the same httpclient as the base uri is still same in location uri (only resource is different).How will I deal this so can avail the benefit of httpclient as a static instance.

```
 private static HttpClient client;
    private static object syncLock = new object();
    public static HttpClient GetHttpClient(IApiConfiguration apiConfiguration)
    {
        if (client == null)
        {
            lock (syncLock)
            {
                if (client == null)
                {
                    client = new HttpClient();

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = false;
                    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(apiConfiguration.Timeout);

                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiConfiguration.BaseUri);

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                   ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(client.BaseAddress).ConnectionLeaseTimeout = apiConfiguration.ConnectionLeaseTimeoutinMilliSec;
                }
            }
        }
        return client;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what the problem is, you should be able to use the same instance of HttpClient to make subsequent requests. Just remember that your BaseAddress MUST contain a slash at the end and your location uri MUST NOT contain a slash at the beginning.

Comment: Also, do you use Dependency Injection at all in your project? That Singleton pattern you're trying to implement is not thread-safe so it's better to let DI handle the creation of HttpClient.

Comment: Hi Janus,Thanks for reply. The location uri is having complete uri and not just the resource.if it was just resource then , i would have just concat baseuri and resource for the subsequent call.

Comment: Also, are you sure the double locking wont help ensuring thread safety?

Comment: So if you pass in the full or complete uri, does that not work? It should ignore the baseaddress if a full address is passed into when you do the GET/POST call

Comment: worrying as the client is singleton Janus- it will mess up the other calls!.I think I should extract the resource from the location uri and make a . subsequent call.

Comment: If I understand, you will have to parse the base uri out of the full uri. But you don't need to use `BaseAddress`. You might find it easier to use a HttpRequestMessage on which you set the uri, headers, etc., then `SendAsync()` it.